# Different Python versions under the same uwsgi Emperor?

Tags: python, uwsgi, virtualenv

I'm running an uwsgi Emperor with various Vassals that each serve a specific Python app from a different virtualenv. Since uwsgi was compiled with it's own Python 2.7 interpreter, trying to use a virtualenv with Python 3 in it produces the following error in vassal.log:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I believe the origin of this error is that uwsgi is using its built-in Python 2.7 interpreter, while the virtualenv directory it's running in only supports Python 3 interpreters. Indeed, when I use another uwsgi (simply by installing it with `pip install uwsgi` in the same virtualenv), the error dissappears. However, I'd like one Emperor to rule over several different virtualenvs, so installing a separate uwsgi in each is not an option.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872801/running-multiple-uwsgi-python-versions) on Stackoverflow, The Right Way to solve this is to compile uwsgi with different Python interpreters as loadable modules. Before I commit to this approach, I'd like to know how I can configure my Vassals to each use another interpreter plugin.

Right now I have one Emperor that is started from my /etc/rc.local with the following settings:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
master = true
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log
```

Then I have a bunch of Vassals with ini files like this:

```
[uwsgi]
master = false
single-interpreter = true
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
virtualenv = /home/user/.virtualenvs/djangoproject
chdir = /home/user/djangoproject
wsgi-file = project/wsgi.py
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

I have no problem compiling a tweaked version of uwsgi with several interpreter plugins, but I'd like to know what I have to change in my configuration to actually *use* these separate interpreters. Can I just say one vassal.ini:

```
plugin = python3.4
```

and in another:

```
plugin = python2.7
```

?

Please help me figure out how to combine Python 2.7 and Python 3 virtualenvs under the same uwsgi Emperor.

Comment: you can follow this paragraph: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary

Comment: This came in handy to build a python 3.6 plugin for uwsgi, https://www.paulox.net/2017/04/04/how-to-use-uwsgi-with-python3-6-in-ubuntu/ I was able to specify which version to use in each vassal depending on which version you want

`plugins=python3`
or
`plugins=python36`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, since I wasn't exactly overwhelmed by responses, here is the solution I came up with myself:

First, I created a new virtualenv with a Python 3 interpreter:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 python3env
```

Then I installed the stock uwsgi from Pypi, which gets compiled automatically with a Python 3 interpreter:

```
pip install uwsgi
```

I created a configuration directory `/etc/uwsgi-python3` that contains the emperor.ini and a subdirectory vassals, containing vassal.ini. Finally, I added the following line to `/etc/rc.local`

```
/home/user/.virtualenvs/python3env/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi-python3/emperor.ini
```

Now there's an uwsgi Emperor running that uses the Python 3 interpreter for its vassals. It doesn't interfere with another uwsgi Emperor that was already running and uses the Python 2.7 interpreter.

I know it's not optimal, because I'm not using the pluggable interpreter architecture that's [explained in the documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary) (thanks roberto! I don't know how I could've overlooked that). However, it runs flawlessly and I didn't have to touch my existing uwsgi installation that's serving a bunch of production apps.

Comment: After struggling with a global `uwsgi` installation, I went with this approach. Nice... +1

Comment: @hedgie: you're a god! I know that there shouldn't be any comments with just a "Thank you!" (upvoted already), but you deserve it. The link for building the single Python plugins didn't work for me on my localized Ubuntu, but starting the uwsgi installed in the virtual environment runs with the correct python version (`./venv/bin/uwsgi --python-version`). Perfect!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with virtualenv on py 2.7.14 and uwsgi installed globally on py 2.7.5. Getting the import site error even though its still all python 2.7

Answer (score 5):

Under osx i made like this.
I unistalled all uwsgi on my system (from brew from pip etc).

After that i downloaded under /usr/local the source code

```
wget https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
```

after

```
cd uwsgi-2.0.17
make PROFILE=nolang
```

In this way i created an executable without plugins for python.

After that i made each plugin for each version on my system:

```
PYTHON=python3.6 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"
PYTHON=python2.7 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python27"
PYTHON=python2.6 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python26"
```

Now i have 3 plugins.

In my ini files for the emperor i specified the plugins dir and the plugin version for each file

```
[uwsgi]
plugins-dir = /usr/local/uwsgi-2.0.17
plugin = python36

[uwsgi]
plugins-dir = /usr/local/uwsgi-2.0.17
plugin = python27

[uwsgi]
plugins-dir = /usr/local/uwsgi-2.0.17
plugin = python26

...
```

I symlinked the uwsgi binary in my /usr/local folder

```
ln -s /usr/local/uwsgi-2.0.17/uwsgi /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

And after run the emperor

```
uwsgi --emperor /PATH/TO/INI/FILES/FOLDER/
```

And voila now i can run python26, python27 and python36 project simultaneously

Comment: There are many solutions around, but this one **really** solved the issue I had running `uwsgi` with `python 3.6`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to reuse the system-wide "emperor", and only substitute the vassal with the new version. This way you don't need to invent any new folders under `/etc` nor launch new services to `rc.local`.

1. Install `uwsgi` via `pip` into a virtualenv.
2. Edit the `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/your-app.ini` as follows:

   - Remove the `plugins=...` line (because pip-compiled `uwsgi` does not support plugins).
   - Add the line:

     ```
     unprivileged-binary-patch = /path/to/your/venv/bin/uwsgi
     ```

     This will force the uWSGI emperor launch your own `uwsgi` binary as the vassal.
3. Reload your app in the emperor `service uwsgi restart your-app`.

The last step somewhy reports a failure to restart the server:

```
 * Starting app server(s) uwsgi
   ...fail!
```

However, in reality, the new vassal starts fine as well as all the other apps. I did not find the time to debug this.